# Java get AudioFormat type for Mic recording

Tags: java, microphone, recording

Today i'm working with microphones and recording.So i found "tutorial"(or actually Oracle javadoc),and i did get Mixer with Line supporting of Microphone.And now i need to get line from mixer.

All is ok,beside AudioFormat.How to get line from Mixer? that is just Mixer.getLine(DataLine.Info).How to get DataLine.Info? Ohh,that is harder.You need Class, and AudioFormat.Class is simple, but how to get AudioFormat? I did try to just create new instance,but i'm getting error.My code:

```
//Sorting Mixers into Mic,and speaker list.
    Info[] MixerList = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();  
    for (int i = 0;i<MixerList.length;i++) {
        Mixer m = AudioSystem.getMixer(MixerList[i]);
        if (m.isLineSupported(Port.Info.MICROPHONE)) MicList.add(m); else ColList.add(m);           
    }

    //Trying to get Line from mixer...And open TDL for recording.
    try {
        DataLine.Info DLI = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, getAudioFormat());
        Mixer m = (Mixer)MicList.toArray()[0];
        Line s = m.getLine(DLI);
        MicRec = (TargetDataLine)s;
        MicRec.open();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {}
```

Now,i'm creating audio format with 8K hz,16bit,and 2 streams.But i'm getting error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line unsupported: interface TargetDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 8000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
```

Soo,how to get AudioFormat? Or did i make a mistace in my "sorting code"?

edit1:Did someting "intresting" with "sorting code".Now i'm writing m.toString() and is it mic,or no.Soo,that was actually good idea,beacos now i see what wrong.

```
com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice@56b65e2b
Is someting else!
com.sun.media.sound.PortMixer@5ee08586
Is someting else!
com.sun.media.sound.PortMixer@4081bfd8
Is mic
```

edit2: Googled,and did find what that is fine.isLineSupporter with port mic mean what mic is  ENABLED,not what that mixer is microphone.